# Getting a list of new, modified and renamed files

Tags: python

I am building a Luigi datapipline that would first get a list of new and modified files in a folder.

I made a GetFileInfo class that gets file_name and hash and populates SQL table. This runs every 30 minutes.

I also made a class CompareFiles where I compare current file_names and their hashes in a folder with that stored in SQL db. As an output I want to get a list of new_files and modified_files. I do not want to get renamed files (different name, same hash) included.

````
    def run(self): 
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
            file_hashes = list(executor.map(self._calculate_file_hash, os.listdir(self.local_folder)))
                
        df = pd.read_sql_table('filesy_state', con=DB_ENGINES[self.engine_name])
      
        new_and_renamed_files = []
        modified_files = []
        
        for file, file_hash in file_hashes:
            match = df[df['file_name'] == file]
            if not match.empty:
                if match.iloc[0]['file_hash'] != file_hash:
                    modified_files.append({'file_name': file})
            else:
                new_and_renamed_files.append({'file_name': file})

        compared_files = {'modified_files': modified_files, 'new_and_renamed_files': new_and_renamed_files}
        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            json.dump(compared_files, outfile)```
````

I cannot figure how to modify my code to only get new files instead of new and renamed together. New files have a hash that doesn't exist in db.

The purpose of this is to then parse new and modified files and populate the SQL Results db with the output (append the output if a new file is parsed and overwrite old records in a modified file is parsed).

Also, am I overcomplicating things here (completely new to coding and pipelines)? I am tied to simple tools like luigi and sqlite that can be run anywhere.

Comment: I'm wondering, what's the point?  You're going to read every byte of every file in the directory tree every time this runs.  Is what you're doing really worth that overhead?  Can't you use the "last changed time" from `stat` to detect changes?

Comment: By the way: How would you handle the case that a file is renamed and changed at the same time? What will you do with the old records of renamed/deleted files in the DB?

Comment: @Green绿色 This is exactly why I am asking which tools, librires and approaches are used for the use-case I described? Parsing flat files at specified locations and sending parsed content to db.

Comment: @TimRoberts Good point. Will use stat instead of hash.